# Safe to delete win 7 from a drive when using win 10 on a different drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10

Before computer upgrade: Running Win7 on a HDD 
After computer upgrade: Running Win10 on an SSD, using old HDD as storage, but it still has all Win7 files on it.

Not running a dual boot setup. 
Didn't use the upgrade tool, Win10 is a fresh install from the commercial USB stick.

I'm like 95% certain I can just delete the 'Windows' folder containing Win7 and be fine, but figured I might as well ask, and whether there are any residual files for Win7 not contained in the 'Windows' folder.

EDIT: formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct - feel free to reformat your HDD or absorb the volume containing your old system files. If you want to make double sure, just shutdown, disconnect the HDD, and power your PC back up - if everything works fine with your SSD, give yourself a pat on the back.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I went ahead and backed up the whole folder just in case. I'm having some issues with folder deletion permissions, but I can ask the Google about that one.

Comment: it’s no problem; it also might be easier to just delete the volume your system files are on - just move anything you want to keep to a different partition first

Answer (score 0):

> I'm like 95% certain I can just delete the 'Windows' folder containing Win7 and be fine[.]

In this particular case, you should encounter no issues if you delete the `Windows` folder on your old HDD.

> I figured I might as well ask whether there are any residual files for Win7 not contained in the `Windows` folder.

Yes, there are undoubtedly some Windows-specific files and folders still hanging around outside the `Windows` folder. However, you will likely want to sort through your remaining files more carefully, as it isn't as easy to just dump certain directories since they may contain other desirable data mixed in with your old Windows files.